# group dict emelents on lists based on key name

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to group dict keys in list of dicts based on dict keys name. The dict keys alawys starts with number for example :

```
{'1_account_id': '5', '1_qty_in': '10.01', '1_uom_in': '1', '2_account_id': '23', '2_qty_in': '2.01', '2_uom_in': '1','3_account_id': '23', '3_qty_in': '2.01', '3_uom_in': '1' ,'some_x':1,'some_y':0}
```

I want to convert that to list grouped by this number like:

```
[{'1':{account_id': '5','qty_in':10.01,'uom_in':1}},{'2':{account_id': '23','qty_in':2.01,'uom_in':1}}....] etc
```

This numbers is not static.

I tried multiple solutions but it seems not good for performace:
Like i looped range for 0 to SOMEBIGNUMBER but this is not a good solution.

i also tried to loop throw the elements to extract the numbers first and then loop again to group but the dict myaybe come not clean as it has other not needed keys.

What should i do ?

Comment: Could you give the exact desired output? It's not clear what you want to do with `'some_x'` and `'some_y'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So given the input `d`

```py
d = {'1_account_id': '5', '1_qty_in': '10.01', '1_uom_in': '1', '2_account_id': '23', '2_qty_in': '2.01', '2_uom_in': '1','3_account_id': '23', '3_qty_in': '2.01', '3_uom_in': '1' ,'some_x':1,'some_y':0}
```

```py
ans = {}
for key in d:
    n,k = key.split('_', 1)
    if n in ans:
        ans[n][k] = d[key]
    else:
        ans[n] = {'account_id': 0, 'qty_in': 0, 'uom_in': 0}
        ans[n][k] = d[key]
```

The above code produces the following output in which the entire output `ans` is a dictionary with the numbers as keys, and the values for each of the keys is also a dictionary, each containing 3 keys and corresponding values :

```
{'1': {'account_id': '5', 'qty_in': '10.01', 'uom_in': '1'},
 '2': {'account_id': '23', 'qty_in': '2.01', 'uom_in': '1'},
 '3': {'account_id': '23', 'qty_in': '2.01', 'uom_in': '1'},
 'some': {'account_id': 0, 'qty_in': 0, 'uom_in': 0, 'x': 1, 'y': 0}}
```

Now to convert it into the list which you have shown in the desired output, use the follwing code. Here we convert the dictionary of dictionaries to a list containing dictionaries.

```py
ans2 = []
for row in ans:
    temp = {}
    temp[row] = ans[row]
    ans2.append(temp)
```

which produces the desired output :

```
 [{'1': {'account_id': '5', 'qty_in': '10.01', 'uom_in': '1'}},
 {'2': {'account_id': '23', 'qty_in': '2.01', 'uom_in': '1'}},
 {'3': {'account_id': '23', 'qty_in': '2.01', 'uom_in': '1'}},
 {'some': {'account_id': 0, 'qty_in': 0, 'uom_in': 0, 'x': 1, 'y': 0}}]
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Mostafa.

You can run this code example to solve it:

```
example_dict = {'1_account_id': '5', '1_qty_in': '10.01', '1_uom_in': '1', '2_account_id': '23', '2_qty_in': '2.01', '2_uom_in': '1','3_account_id': '23', '3_qty_in': '2.01', '3_uom_in': '1' ,'some_x':1,'some_y':0}
desired_keys = ['account_id','qty_in','uom_in']

result = {}
for key,value in example_dict.items():
  key_num, key_name = key.split('_', 1)
  if key_name in desired_keys:
    result.setdefault(key_num, {})[key_name] = value

print(result)

{'1': {'accountid': '5', 'qtyin': '10.01', 'uomin': '1'}, '2': {'accountid': '23', 'qtyin': '2.01', 'uomin': '1'}, '3': {'accountid': '23', 'qtyin': '2.01', 'uomin': '1'}, 'some': {'x': 1, 'y': 0}}
```

It will print (as you desired):

```
{'1': {'accountid': '5', 'qtyin': '10.01', 'uomin': '1'}, '2': {'accountid': '23', 'qtyin': '2.01', 'uomin': '1'}, '3': {'accountid': '23', 'qtyin': '2.01', 'uomin': '1'}, 'some': {'x': 1, 'y': 0}}
```

Tell me if you do not understand something.

Comment: i want to ignore the some.. i don't want any other keys in this dict only the account_id,qty_in,uom_in

Comment: How are the original data stored? In a text file?

Comment: Of course, just do an if ... I modified it to work. It works fine now.